# getElement is not a function TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an abstract class in a TypeScript file which is imported by another TypeScript file. In my ionViewWillEnter() method, I attempt to call a method from the imported file's object, and I am met with these errors:

> TypeError: ctx.this.testObject.getNumber is not a function

> TypeError: ctx.this.testObject.setNumber is not a function

Here's the important bits of both files:

**Object file**

```
export abstract class TestObjectAbs {
  constructor(jsonData: any) {
  };
  public num: number = 5;
  public ID: number;
  public setNumber(num: number){
    this.num = num;
  }
  public getNumber(){
    return this.num;
  }
}

class TestObject implements TestObjectAbs{
  constructor(jsonData: any) {
    super();
  }
}
```

**File that should use object**

```
import { TestObjectAbs } from "../../services/object.service";

export class Page implements OnInit {
  this.user = await this.app.getUser();
  await this.user.getObject(this.api, ID);
  public testObject: TestObjectAbs = null;

  async ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.testObject = await this.user.getMatch(this.api, profileID); //This returns an object of type TestObject, not TestObjectAbs
    this.testObject.setNumber(10);
    console.log(this.testObject.getNumber());
}
```

**getMatch function**

```
public async getMatch(api: ApiService, ID) {
    var temp = TempdataService.getObjects();
    for(let i=0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      if(temp[i].ID == ID){
        return temp[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
   }
```

**getObjects function**

```
public static getObjects(): TestObject[] {
    return [{num: 1, ID: 1,}, {num: 2, ID: 2,}, {num: 3, ID: 3,}, {num: 4, ID: 4,}, {num: 5, ID: 5,},] }
```

`console.log(this.testObject.num)` seems to work, but neither function works. The imports are correct, `getUser()` works, `getObject()` works and have been tested. The only thing not working are the function calls for `TestObjects`.

Comment: What is `this.testObject`? Where is it initialize/declared in the Page class (or anywhere in its prototype chain)?

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I forgot to include some important code. It's there now. Let me know if you have any insight or any more questions!

Comment: @Slash How does function `this.user.getMatch` look like?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko I've added the function and accompanying function. It's just a temporary function that returns a TestObject when the user inputs something into the address using APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getObjects` not returns `TestObject[]`. It returns just array of objects. You should use the constructor of `TestObject` somewhere. For example, you can update `getMatch` in this way:

```
public async getMatch(api: ApiService, ID): TestObject {
    var temp = TempdataService.getObjects();

    for (let i=0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if(temp[i].ID == ID) {
            return new TestObject(temp[i]);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And update `getObjects` declaration:

```
public static getObjects(): any[] {
    return [
        {num: 1, ID: 1,},
        {num: 2, ID: 2,},
        {num: 3, ID: 3,},
        {num: 4, ID: 4,},
        {num: 5, ID: 5,}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey! I've updated the post with more code I forgot to include which appears to be similar to your answer in that I have an alternate class which implements the abstract class. The issue persists. Do you have any more insight?

Comment: @Slash I updated my answer according to the new code. Also, your `TestObject` constructor probably should use `super(jsonData)` instead of `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the abstract class wrong.
You should be extending from it and not implementing it like an interface, at least that's what I'm guessing you're trying to ultimately achieve.

```
class TestObject extends TestObjectAbs{
    constructor(jsonData: any) {
        super(jsonData);
        this.setNumber() // not undefined aynmore
    }
}
```